# Results on the largest prime factor of $2^n+1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, factorization

A work of [Cameron Stewart](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.1274.pdf) (the paper has appeared in Acta Mathematica),  proving a conjecture of Erdos, Stewart shows that 
the largest prime factor of $2^n-1$ is at least 
$n \times \exp\Big( \frac{\log n}{104 \log \log n}\Big)$ ,
if $n$ is large enough.

[Zsigmondy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem)  is on the same topic.

I would like to know about the largest prime factor of $2^n+1$. I have searched, but most of the time result of the largest prime factor of $2^n-1$  appears.

My questions is-

1. Is there any *result regarding the largest prime factor* of $2^n+1$ ?

if you know anything related to the problem, please inform.

Comment: Hmm, because $2^n+1 = (2^{2n}-1)/(2^n-1)$ - isn't then the greatest prime factor of$2^n+1$ likely/in many cases that of $2^{2n}-1$ (because the greatest primefactor of the latter should-according to the formula- be larger than that of $2^n-1$) ?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms  Why? The bound for the greatest prime factor of $2^{2n} - 1$ is smaller than $4n^2$, much smaller than $2^n - 1$.

Comment: At least when $n$ is odd, the result of Stewart still applies and gives the same bound.

Answer (score 8):

One has $2^n+1= \frac{2^{2n}-1}{2^n-1} = \prod_{d \mid 2n,~d\nmid n} \Phi_d(2,1)$. In particular, $\Phi_{2n}(2,1)$ divides $2^n+1$, and so the main theorem of Stewart's paper shows immediately that $P(2^n+1) > 2n \exp(\log(2n)/104\log\log(2n))$ for large $n$.